# Get data based on field, which is evaluated on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, filtering

I have array of objects as below:

```
var data = [
    { SrNo: 1, BabyName: 'A', ParentName: 'X' },
    { SrNo: 2, BabyName: 'D', ParentName: 'X' },
    { SrNo: 3, BabyName: 'B', ParentName: 'Y' },
    { SrNo: 4, BabyName: 'E', ParentName: 'Y' },
    { SrNo: 5, BabyName: 'C', ParentName: 'Z' }
]
```

I get input as array of `BabyNames` and I have to find `ParentNames` for them, and then filter data on `ParentNames` as output.

```
input = ['A','B'];
```

So, if my input is `['A','B']` my expected output is array of 4 objects (SrNo 1,2,3,4)

What I have done to achieve

```
//filter all objects for matching BabyNames
var a1 = _.filter(data, function (item) { return _.contains(input, item["BabyName"]); })

//pluck ParentNames from a1 array of objects and take unique
var a2 = _.uniq(_.pluck(a1,"ParentName"))

//filter all objects (original data set) on ParentName with a2 as input
var a3 = _.filter(data, function (item) { return _.contains(a2, item["ParentName"]); })
```

I find this not an efficient way, but couldn't come to any other solution.
Please guide.

Comment: Is SrNo inheriting the object properties from BabyName which is inheriting properties from parentName? Not sure how to read the above object diagram.

Comment: _"array of objects as below"_, that's not an array of objects. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the input data variable

Comment: basically you need to iterate at least 2 times the data array, one for getting the parents and one to filter  for the result. you could overcome the middle step, if you use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), or an object as hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to iterate at least 2 times the data array, one for getting the parents and one to filter  for the result. you could overcome the middle step, if you use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), or an object as hash table.

This is a proposal in ES6.

```js
var data = [{ SrNo: 1, BabyName: 'A', ParentName: 'X' }, { SrNo: 2, BabyName: 'D', ParentName: 'X' }, { SrNo: 3, BabyName: 'B', ParentName: 'Y' }, { SrNo: 4, BabyName: 'E', ParentName: 'Y' }, { SrNo: 5, BabyName: 'C', ParentName: 'Z' }],
    input = ['A', 'B'],
    babies = new Set(input),
    parents = new Set,
    result;

data.forEach(a => babies.has(a.BabyName) && parents.add(a.ParentName));
result = data.filter(a => parents.has(a.ParentName));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is another way](https://jsfiddle.net/8c2ht80z/1/) to get the result.

```
var input = ['A', 'B'];

function getParents(input, filterProp, returnProp) {
  var filtered = data.filter(function(d) {
    return input.indexOf(d[filterProp]) !== -1;
  });
  if (returnProp) {
    return filtered.map(function(d) {
      return d[returnProp];
    });
  }
  return filtered;
}

// get the result by first filter with baby name and return parent names
// then filter with parent names
getParents(getParents(input, "BabyName", "ParentName"), "ParentName");
```